# Laravel do not retrieve double value from database

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, inner-join

I have been trying to get price data from table 'rates' and store it in another table 'bookings'.

```
$duit =Booking::Join('rates', 'bookings.park_area','=', 'rates.areaid')
    ->where('bookings.user_id', '=', Auth::user()->userid)
    ->where('bookings.park_area','=',$bookings->park_area)
    ->where('bookings.semester','=',$bookings->semester)
    ->first(['rates.price']);  
$bookings->price=($duit);
    $bookings->save();
```

However, i get an error stating that the value retrieve is not of a double datatype: {"price":80}. So, I tried changing `first(['rates.price']);` to `value('rates.price')` but it stores as null.

So, why does {"price":80} become null and how to get the value of 80?

Comment: Try var_dump the $duit and check what it gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can used like that use `select` method here or directly get

get object value directly **`->first()->price`** instead or this  -**`->first(['rates.price']);`**

```
$duit = Booking::Join('rates', 'bookings.park_area','=', 'rates.areaid')
    ->where('bookings.user_id', '=', Auth::user()->userid)
    ->where('bookings.park_area','=',$bookings->park_area)
    ->where('bookings.semester','=',$bookings->semester)
    ->select('rates.price')
    ->first()->price;  

$bookings->price = $duit;
$bookings->save();
```